# Associate existing IAM role with EC2 instance in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How can I use an existing IAM role for an EC2 instance, as opposed to creating a new one in my CloudFormation template?

For example, I have created a role in AWS Console and just want to use that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need an instance profile, a role, and the instance info (or launch configuration) itself.

Your instance profile would look like this:

```
"Resources" : {
  "InstanceProfile" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
    "Properties" : {
      "Path" : "/",
      "Roles" : ["MyExistingRole"]
    }
  },

  "Instance" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties" : {
      "IamInstanceProfile" : {"Ref" : "InstanceProfile"}
      ...
    }
  }
```

***In particular - note that the reference in the Instance profile is to an existing RoleName***

Also -  [I've written about bootstrapping instances](http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/08/05/bootstrapping-on-aws/) which uses instance profiles and roles to ensure we're not persisting security.

The key thing is rather than using the {"Ref" : RoleName} etc, to use the actual name of the role.

Comment: The ref: rolename can refer to a section in the parameters if you want to parameterize your cfn script.

Comment: +1 for specifying that only the role *name* should be used. For example, this will fail "Roles" : [ "role/MyExistingRole" ]

Comment: +1, It is not obvious from documentation, it should be added here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-iaminstanceprofile

Answer (score 33):

You can use an existing InstanceProfile instead of creating a new one from within the stack. In fact, one might already be created for you - from [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html):

> If you use the AWS Management Console to create a role for Amazon EC2, the console **automatically creates** an instance profile and gives it the same name as the role.

This means that you might not have to create an `AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile` resource in the stack. However note that also:

> The console **does not create** an instance profile for a role that is not associated with Amazon EC2.

In this case you can do it manually from AWS CLI using these 2 commands:

```
aws iam create-instance-profile --instance-profile-name MyExistingRole
aws iam add-role-to-instance-profile --instance-profile-name MyExistingRole --role-name MyExistingRole
```

Then, provided you've defined a role in the UI named `MyExistingRole`, this will be sufficient:

```
"Resources" : {

  "Instance" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    ...
    "Properties" : {
      "IamInstanceProfile" : "MyExistingRole",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, this saved me the two minutes that cfn takes to create instance profiles. If anyone has issues with this method make sure to verify that your role has a trusted relationship with ec2.amazonaws.com.

Answer (score 2):

for those using launch templates the syntax is a little different compared to ec2instance or launch configs.

below is yaml example where you are using launch templates.

```
LaunchTemplate:
  Properties:
    LaunchTemplateData:
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Name: !Ref ExistingInstanceProfileName
```

Comment: This was useful for me as I wanted to provide the name of an existing profile name.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with the IAM role?

I have a cfn script that needs access to a restricted S3 bucket.  My instance block looks like this - bucketName and RoleName are both parameters, with defaults:

```
"Resources" : {
    "myInstance" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",

        "Metadata" : {
            "Comment1" : "My Instance stuff here",     

            "AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication": {
                "default" : {
                    "type": "s3",
                    "buckets": [ { "Ref" : "bucketName" } ],
                    "roleName": { "Ref" : "RoleName" }
                }
            },
...snip...
```

Edit:  I include the role as part of the properties when creating the instance:

```
        "Properties" : {
            "ImageId"             : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "64"] },
            "InstanceType"        : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
            "SecurityGroups"      : [ {"Ref" : "SecurityGroup"} ],
            "IamInstanceProfile"  : { "Ref" : "RoleName" },
            "KeyName"             : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },

            "BlockDeviceMappings" : [
                {
                    "DeviceName" : "/dev/sda1",
                    "Ebs" : { "VolumeSize" : "10" } 
                }
            ],

            "UserData"            : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                "#!/bin/bash -v\n",
...snip...
            ] ] } }
```

And the RoleName is defined in my Parameters section:

```
"Parameters" : {

    "RoleName" : {
        "Description" : "Role description",
        "Type" : "String",
        "Default" : "my-default-role",
        "ConstraintDescription" : "Must be a valid IAM Role"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Primarily with s3.  However from a understanding perspective I would like to know for others, such as managing ec2.  Reason being I want to at some point set up an orchestration machine.

I'm editing my template in Visual Studio.  Using your example it still says I need to define a AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile... :(

Comment: I tried this way by creating a parameter entry and assigning my existing IAM role as the default and then adding the Ref line for IamInstanceProfile in the Properties section.  When i launch the template, it takes about 15 minutes and then fails so the template is valid but it doesnt create any instances.  If i remove the single line from the properties, it creates instances but obviously without the role.  So looks like, as @Bevan said, that it may need the AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile defiinition

Answer (score 0):

Just enter Existing Role name created in the Amazon console to the EC2 resource IamInstanceProfile property.

```
Resources:
  TestEC2Instace:
     Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
     InstanceType: t2.micro
     IamInstanceProfile: ExistingRoleName
     Tags:
       - Key: Name
         Value: Public Instance
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Resources" : {
    "Instance" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
       ...
      "Properties" : {
      "IamInstanceProfile" : "MyExistingRole",
    ...
  }
 } 
}
```

This did not work for me.  Got an error in cloudformation. Can't assign a role name where Instance profile is expected.
I have 2 different stacks - one that creates the IAM role & another that creates the EC2 instance.

I exported the RoleName from the stack that creates the IAM role and in the EC2 stack referenced it in the roles of the instance profile:

```
InstanceProfile:
   Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
   Properties: 
     InstanceProfileName: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-InstanceProfile
     Path: "/"
     Roles: 
       - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-ServerRole
```