# How to launch EC2 instance using AWS cloudformation

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami, aws-marketplace

I've submitted my AMI to the AWS Marketplace but it has been rejected saying I need to convert my manual instructions into a CloudFormation template. My manual instructions for the users currently state that:

```
- User must create a new Role
- Assign AWSS3FullAccess to this role
- Launch the AMI with WebSecurityGroup (port 80 and 443)
```

I have not used CloudFormation before so I would like to ask a couple of questions

1. Is it possible to create a CloudFormation template such that it would: 1) create a new role 2) assign a policy to this role 3) Create an EC2 Instance with  the AMI (amiID would be specified) with this role and WebSecurityGroup.
2. I've created the following template that creates a new role and assigns it full S3 access.

But I'm not sure how to do the rest. How can I launch an EC2 instance with this new role and specify my AMI id?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Sample

Resources:
  MyAmiRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
      Path: "/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your Amazon CloudFormation template, you would define the following resources:

- `IAM::Role` (as you have already done)
- `IAM::InstanceProfile` (which allows a Role to be assumed by an Amazon EC2 instance)
- `EC2::SecurityGroup`
- `AWS::EC2::Instance` which would refer to the `InstanceProfile`, your AMI and the Security Group

For some examples, see:

- [IAM Role with Embedded Policy and Instance Profiles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-templateexamples)
- [Associating an existing IAM role with AWS::EC2::Instance in CloudFormation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329067/associating-an-existing-iam-role-with-awsec2instance-in-cloudformation)
- [AWS CloudFormation Resource Types Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html)

The last link typically provides examples with each resource type, so it's a matter of copying the examples and then customizing for your use-case.