# Attach a preexisting role in template.yml file while creating sam application through console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to create a sam application with a pre existing role  through sam-cli.By default the sam clil creates new user roles with basic lambda exuection policies ,but as i want to run x-ray on my sam application i would want application to be created with existing  user role.

Here is my template.yml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  POCLambdaExecutionRole:
  Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
  SAMLocal:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: SAMLocal.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
    TracingConfig:
      Mode: Active
      Environment:
        Variables:
          dev_table: "MessageQueue"
      Events:
        SAMLocal:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: GET
  SAMLocal1:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: SAMLocal.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
```

How can i achieve the same .

found this article on stack overflow but does not really helps my casue [Associate existing IAM role with EC2 instance in CloudFormation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329067/associate-existing-iam-role-with-ec2-instance-in-cloudformation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to put existing role in your yaml file in ARN format

role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/role

Comment: i got the follwing error when tried your appraoch :property role not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::Function.Putting role under Properties:   is this the correct way?

Comment: You need to define LamdaExecutionRole:LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com you can also refer the Lamda template guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-lambda.html

Comment: now using it under resources like this  :LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      role: arn:aws:iam::337226440425:role/POCLambdaExecutionRole        didnt worked ..can you please share a example where i just use the existing role for all functions and dont want to add any policies in yaml

Comment: can you please confirm if issue is resolved at your end? use Role: 'arn:aws:iam::AccountID:role/lambda_basic_execution'

Answer (score 0):

you can either set role or permission. If you do not define role for your funcition, SAM will create one role for every function. by default, it will scope for each funcition individually.

Declare Role outside your function in the fashion i have described in my solution role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/role

[Check THIS](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/)