# aws: cloudformation: How to pass the role arn to instanceprofile

Tags: aws-cloudformation

My goal is to create an EC2 instance with a specific role already created by my admin for me.

```
# in mumbai region (working)
Resources:
  MyNewEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0fcbc9ed97efe271e
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SubnetId: subnet-fc2df495
      KeyName: sant-test
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref Ec2InstanceProfile

  Ec2InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - "arn:aws:iam::yyyyyyy:role/xxxxx"
```

When i run the above cloudformation i am getting the following error

```
Resource handler returned message: "The specified value for roleName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_-
```

How to resolve this.

I tried using only the role name

```
# in mumbai region (working)
Resources:
  MyNewEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0fcbc9ed97efe271e
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SubnetId: subnet-fc2df495
      KeyName: sant-test
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref Ec2InstanceProfile

  Ec2InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - "xxxxx"
```

Now i see the stack is stuck at resource creation initated

[image]

Comment: Just `xxxxx` instead of the arn!?

Comment: can you check my updated questin. i tried xxxxx

Comment: Try getting rid of the quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may require "Ref" as the key and the role name as the value. Refer the example at the end of this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-instanceprofile.html#cfn-iam-instanceprofile-roles).

**Update**: Please ignore the above sentence. I think you can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342616/7630468) for the correct syntax to associate an existing IAM role which is in JSON format. If we convert it into YAML format, the syntax should be:

```
Instanceprofile:    
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile'    
    Properties:      
      Path: /      
      Roles:        
        - MyExistingRole
```